# ¿Hay alguna expresión en castellano para “elephant in the room”?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Esta pregunta en rigor no es originalmente mía sino de este señor, que es decano de una universidad argentina:

[image]

El Merriam-Webster define *[elephant in the room](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elephant%20in%20the%20room)* como

> an obvious major problem or issue that people avoid discussing or
>   acknowledging

o sea, "un problema o asunto obvio de gran importancia que la gente evita debatir o reconocer". Algunos ejemplos (de [aquí](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/the_elephant_in_the_room)):

- ‘they've steadfastly ignored the elephant in the room: the ever-growing debt burden on graduates’
- ‘I also think the Small decisions are interesting because they completely avoid the elephant in the room: the Second Amendment.’
- ‘Here in Britain the issue of illegal immigration used to be like the elephant in the room that everyone pretended not to notice.’

Un ejemplo que me viene a mí a la mente es el actual debate soterrado (en la mayoría de las sociedades occidentales) sobre cómo sostener un sistema de pensiones, jubilaciones, retiros (o como se llame en cada país) cuando las personas viven cada vez más años luego de dejar su empleo formal. Otro sería la constatación de que los países menos desarrollados se están encontrando con que para no empeorar el calentamiento global deberían privarse del uso de recursos de los cuales los países más desarrollados abusaron sin culpa hasta ahora. Pero no tienen que ser temas de macroeconomía o geopolítica, por supuesto.

Comment: Ninguna razón, simplemente quiero saber si existe una expresión "original" similar que no sea un calco.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but you might want to look up the phrase "secreto a voces".  It's a parallel concpt,  the secret that everybody knows.

Comment: It´s interesting to note here that the Merrian-Webster definition cited here is what [tabú][https://dle.rae.es/?id=YtmZJ7h] means

Comment: @pablodf76 I am still waiting for you to reply to my comments on the answer at https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/35044/edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ¿Hay alguna expresión en castellano para “elephant in the room”?

Parece ser que no, ya que esa misma pregunta fue hecha en Wordreference ([¿Alguna expresión en español que corresponda a "The elephant in the room"?](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/elephant-in-the-room.156888/), en 2009, hace diez años) y en Quora ([How do Spanish speakers translate "the elephant in the room"](https://www.quora.com/How-do-Spanish-speakers-translate-the-elephant-in-the-room-a-difficult-situation-that-people-close-to-it-willfully-don%E2%80%99t-want-to-face), preguntada hace un par de años) y el resumen del contenido de ambos post es que no hay una expresión similar en castellano que no sea una traducción literal de la inglesa.

Mención especial tiene esta contribución del usuario "piccipanni"en el post de Wordreference, que explica que

> Así es que fue utilizada la expresión inglesa [“elephant in the room”] por primera vez en 1959..., y luego se popularizó (ver en Wikipedia): "Es un problema similar a tener un elefante en la sala de estar. Es tan grande que no puedes ignorarlo.

pero que sin embargo

> Una referencia similar para el ámbito cultural español (cuyo origen se remonta al "Conde Lucanor" de Don Juan Manuel, de 1335 (aunque la historia fuese después realmente popularizada por los hermanos Grimm) sería la del "traje invisible del emperador".
>   Podría hacerse referencia a que ¡"Es un '¡el rey va desnudo"!, que nadie se anima/atreve a exclamar.

(Otro de los posts le corrige y explica que el cuento era de Andersen y no de los Grimm)

Así que otra manera de decir "that's the elephant in the room (that you can't ignore but that nobody seems to want to talk about)" podría ser

> Ese es el rey/emperador al que nadie se atreve a decirle que va desnudo

Comment: Así es @Diego, la referencia al rey desnudo también la pensé. Lo notable es cómo la frase—surginda de la tradición literaria rusa hace dos siglos— conquistó los imaginarios culturales de muchas lenguas precisamente porque no poseían una formulación como esa

Answer (score 4):

El castellano tiene una expresión popular bastánte próxima en su sentido (no en cuanto al objeto,— no percibido—, sino a la actitud negadora de quien se rehusa a reconocer su existencia)

> ***No hay peor ciego que el que no quiere ver***

Entiendo que la expresión de Levy Yeyati —sobre tener que crear la traducción sajona de ese dicho— era retórica, para echar luz sobre los piqueteros y la problemática de quienes están laboralmente  precarizados, pero atendiendo la pregunta, sobre modos propios, durante el [Coloquio de IDEA donde habló](https://www.lanacion.com.ar/economia/contratarian-piquetero-una-incomoda-pregunta-sorprendio-empresarios-nid2298386) también podría haber dicho:

> *Nuestra peor ceguera es la de no querer ver el trabajo informal en Argentina*

Es de notar que la expresión  *Un elefante en la habitación* [como recoge wikipedia en su versión en inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_in_the_room) tiene un orígen literario, por una referencia de Fyodor Dostoevsky a raíz de cuento de Iván Krylov publicado en 1814.

La frase proveniente de la literatura rusa de hace dos siglos aporta una metáfora excelente sobre algo que pese a ser evidente alguien no ve  Y si se piensa sobre ello, no es casual que  haya surgido  de la imaginación literaria, —sin estar presente por lo visto en la fraseologia popular de las principales tradiciones linguísticas—, por estar aludiendo al (grotesco) imposible de que un animal asi de inmenso no sea visto en un ambiente reducido por cuatro paredes. (En español se usa también decir ***"como un elefante en un bazar [o cristaleria]"*** ilustrando la torpeza dañosa de alguien en una circunstancia donde el mayor tacto y delicadeza son necesarios)

Comment: Quizá no me hago entender bien. La versión literal es comprensible pero es un calco reciente del inglés. Normalmente al preguntar por expresiones o palabras tratamos de buscar y detallar apariciones de las mismas en los medios, en textos y videos, etc. No estoy seguro de que "elefante en la sala" o similares estén realmente difundidos y aceptados en castellano, como para decir que el calco del inglés ya está adoptado.

Comment: @pablodf76 tienes razón, en cuanto a que no es un dicho popular sino de un origen culto de un autor ruso. Actualicé mi respuesta por eso

Answer (score 1):

Una expresión común que se refiere a asuntos especialmente difíciles es **papa caliente**.

> Los antiguos gobernantes con su política de consentimiento han permitido que el monto de la deuda aumente dejándonos la **papa caliente**.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly the same, but there is an expression to say there is something very obvious but anyway someone could not see it (colloquial): "si fuera perro (eso) te mordería"

Comment: Esa la uso yo cuando no encuentro algo, miro alrededor sin verlo, lo busco por un buen rato y luego estaba casi a simple vista o muy cerca de mi. Entonces digo "Si llega a ser un lobo me come". Pero eso tiene un sentido completamente distinto al elefante ne la habitación. En este caso todos lo ven pero nadie quiere hablar de ello.

Comment: Si es interesante esta acepción porque alude a una situación de ceguera parcial respecto de algo que no percibimos, pese a tenerlo cerca (en la versión del noroeste argentino, cuando se detecta algo que (generalmente se está buscando y) no se veía previamente, —y ese algo resultaba estar  muy próximo a uno— se usa comentar, decir \[se\]: "*si fuera víbora \[me\] te picaba*")

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo más cercano sería "Hacerse de la vista gorda"

Answer (score 0):

Abrir un melón es una expresión reciente que significa algo muy parecido a addressing the elephant in the room.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!